# Accessing properties using for...in

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access the properties of this object:

```
var obj = {hello: 1, world: 2};
```

This gives me back undefined:

```
function foo(a) {
  for(property in a) {
    console.log(a.property);
  }
  return "foo";
}

foo(obj);
```

This gives the intended result:

```
function bar(a) {
  for(property in a) {
    console.log(a[property]);
  }
  return "bar";
}

bar(obj);
```

Why does the call to foo not work, while the call to bar allows me to access the properties?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: ...because there's no property called `property`?

Comment: @TimCooper : Tangentially related, that link seems to discuss best practice, whereas I think the OP is asking for an explanation of why he gets an undefined when he uses the (obviously) wrong syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `a.property` is the same as `a['property']`, not `a[property]`. So you actually try to access the property "property".

Your second code snippet uses the variable `property`, the former uses the property `property`.